# Does Cloud Run add location-aware request header similar to App engine?

Tags: google-cloud-run

App engine requests have location-aware headers (`X-AppEngine-Country`, `X-AppEngine-Region`, `X-AppEngine-City`) automatically added. Does Cloud Run have something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (will be) possible with Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer via [user-defined headers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/user-defined-request-headers).

**However,** putting your Cloud Run service behind the load balancer is **currently in alpha**, so you cannot try this out today. You can wait for a while, or if you’re willing try the alpha out and give feedback, please contact me. `#ahmetbtodo`

Comment: is it ready now?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, these Google custom header values doesn't exist today. However, in the current headers you can find the IP of the originated requester (here in IPv6)

```
forwarded: for="2a01:cb14:af0:b500:ccf6:1a91:1713:b48";proto=https
x-forwarded-for: 2a01:cb14:af0:b500:ccf6:1a91:1713:b48*emphasized text*
```

You can use external services to know the exact location.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is because of Knative API/behavior consistency.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google, I thought that was to let user switching easily from a platform (managed) to another one (Knative). I update my wrong assumption.